# IIS Server only accesible on port 80 within network

Tags: networking, iis, iis-8

I have an IIS 8 server running under Windows Server 2012. When it is accessed over port 80, I can access it from within the network. With an internal IP address of 192.168.1.14, I can go to 192.168.1.14 from other computers' browsers in the network and access the page. However, when I change the port from the site bindings settings to port 8080 (and a few other ports have been tried), I can still access 192.168.1.14:8080 from IE on the server itself, but not from other computers on the network.

This screenshot shows how I set up the port and the connection error. Firefox is on a different machine on the network, whereas Internet Explorer is running on the server:

[image: This screenshot shows how I set up the port and the connection error. Firefox is on a different machine on the network, whereas Internet Explorer is running on the server.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely problem is Windows Firewall. Configure it to allow port 8080 traffic. It allows port 80 by default when IIS is installed as a role, but it doesn't automatically configure itself if you change the port.

Comment: That did it. I was able to create a new inbound rule to allow port 8080.